# Updating Information in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update the informations on my listview by using sqlitedatabase, so in my update class I'm getting an error which is here on the pic http://prntscr.com/djbe3i

Here's the dbhelper method code:

```
 public int updateInformation(String old_name, String new_name,String old_hours, String new_hours, String old_department,String new_department,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.Name,new_name);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.RenderedHours,new_hours);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.Department,new_department);

    String selection = UserContract.NewUserInfo.Name + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selection_args = {old_name};
    int count = sqLiteDatabase.update(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selection_args);
    return count;

}
```

Update class code:

```
  public void updateContact(View view) {

    userDBHelper = new UserDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String name,hours,department;

    name = new_name.getText().toString();
    hours = new_hours.getText().toString();
    department = new_department.getText().toString();
int count = userDBHelper.updateInformation(search_id,NewName,NewHours,NewDepartment,sqLiteDatabase);

}
}
```

EDIT: I changed the code into:

```
public void updateContact(View view) {

    userDBHelper = new UserDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String name,hours,department;

    name = new_name.getText().toString();
    hours = new_hours.getText().toString();
    department = new_department.getText().toString();
    int count =  userDBHelper.updateInformation(search,name,hours,department,sqLiteDatabase);

}
```

and I'm still getting error I don't understand.

2ND EDIT: I get it now okay, I just mistyped the string and the arguments that i needed for the update contact i replaced the code into:

```
 int count = userDBHelper.updateInformation(search_id,name,hours,department,sqLiteDatabase);
```

DBHelper.updateInformation code:

```
public int updateInformation(String old_name, String new_name, String new_hours,String new_department,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
```

Comment: Count your parameters and you should be able to figure this out. The IDE is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Your two arguments: `String old_department`, `String new_department` are missing

Comment: And also you added edittext to function not string check the function.Actually the function has seven parameters but you are passing five parameters only

Comment: I got it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it now my parameters doesn't match and I fixed it by changing the code into:

```
public int updateInformation(String old_name, String new_name, String new_hours,String new_department,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
```

Then changing the code in update class:

```
int count = userDBHelper.updateInformation(search_id,name,hours,department,sqLiteDatabase);
```